# jQuery/Javascript variable concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a function to write out text with a typewriter effect. I want to change the text to be written out. Let me show you!

Now I have:

```
 $.each((text).split('') ...
 var text = "Some text here"
```

So now it uses the text in the `text` variable. What I want to do is, to have multiple texts, and to be able to choose as following:

`slotNumber` contains a number, eg 1, 2, 3 or 4 etc...
What I want to achieve is, to have mutiple text variables:

```
var text1 = "Some text" 
var text2 = "Some other text" 
var text3 = "Another text"
```

and to be able to use some concatenation, so that with

```
 $.each(('text' + slotNumber).split('') ...
```

I use text1, text2 or text3 resp., depending on what `slotNumber` contains.
I know, that `('text' + slotNumber).split('')` is incorrect, but what would be the correct way? Thank you!

Comment: for global vars, use `window['text' + slotNumber].split ...`

Comment: This is what arrays are for. (And global variables are evil, avoid them)

Comment: @Jaromanda X The window solution works, and it's easy, thank you!

Comment: Quentin's right (though comma splices are evil, too :) ). Use an array and reference by index, or use an object array and reference by ID.

Comment: @Quentin, would you care to elaborate, how exactly in this case? :) Thank you!

Comment: var text = []; text[0] = ... etc

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how the duplicate indicated helps resolve this question.